# RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, autograd

I get the error like the title....and I found some answers so I try `retain_graph=True`, but it doesn't work. Maybe my code got another problems (it occurs in `loss_actor.backward(retain_grah....)`)

```py
q = torch.zeros(len(reward))
q_target = torch.zeros(len(reward))
for j, r in enumerate(reward):
    q_target[j] = self.critic_network(torch.transpose(next_state[j], 0, 1), self.actor_network(torch.transpose(next_state[j], 0, 1)).view(1, 1))
    q_target[j] = r + (done[j] * gamma * q_target[j]).detach()
    q[j] = self.critic_network(torch.transpose(state[j], 0, 1), action[j].view(1, 1))
loss_critic = F.mse_loss(q, q_target)
self.critic_optimizer.zero_grad()
loss_critic.backward()
self.critic_optimizer.step()

b = torch.zeros(len(reward))
for j, r in enumerate(reward):
    b[j] = self.critic_network(torch.transpose(state[j], 0, 1), self.actor_network(torch.transpose(state[j], 0, 1)).view(1, 1))
loss_actor = -torch.mean(b)
self.actor_optimizer.zero_grad()
loss_actor.backward(retain_graph=True)
self.actor_optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided info about part of your computational graph, I  assume, that `loss_actor` and `loss_critic` share some parts of it, I think its `state` (not sure)

```sh
state -> q --> loss_critic <-- backward 1
|
-------> b --> loss_actor <--- backward 2
```

to reproduce your example:

```py
# Some computations that produce state
state = torch.ones((2, 2), requires_grad=True) ** 2

# Compute the first loss
q = torch.zeros((1))
q[0] = state[0, 0]
l1 = torch.sum(2 * q)
l1.backward()

# Compute the second loss
b = torch.zeros((1))
b[0] = state[1, 1]
l2 = torch.mean(2 * b)
l2.backward()
```

```py
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-2ab509bedf7a> in <module>
     10 b[0] = state[1, 1]
     11 l2 = torch.mean(2 * b)
---> 12 l2.backward()
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.
```

Trying

```py
...
l2.backward(retain_graph=True)
```

doesn't help, because you have to

> Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.

here, on the first backward call (for `l1`)

```py
l1.backward(retain_graph=True)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I realized this problem and l revise it. But now I get another  new thing:I have two agents so the same network: a and b. They use the same data .But if one has got the update the grad,anonther would get wrong: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation. In my opinion ,state would change in the first time,so it results in the wrong in the second time of updating. Is there right way to avoid?

Comment: @Mr_qiaozhi If still facing the issue, please consider opening another question with the updated code.